# How to add linebreak in GridView Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am displaying data in `GridView`. I have specified `Label` `Width` for `ItemTemplate`.
Japanese characters are displayed with linebreaks but english characters are displayed without linebreaks. So my `GridView`'s shape is getting weird.
Please guide me.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridCustomer" Width="750px" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
              CellPadding="4" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="GridCustomer_PageIndexChanging" 
              AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridCustomer_Sorting" 
              OnRowDataBound="GridCustomer_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridCustomer_RowCommand" 
              Font-Names="ＭＳ 明朝" Font-Size="15px">
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="顧客名称" SortExpression="Name" HeaderStyle-Width="170px">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" Width="100px" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' Width="150px"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="住所" SortExpression="Address" HeaderStyle-Width="160px">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" Width="100px" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' Width="170px"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you do line break using `<br/>`

Comment: @Webruster I did not understand. my point is if I have specified Label Width then irrespective of characters linebreak should be occured after specified pixels.

Comment: your problem is gonna solve

Comment: please can anyone explain this to me with example code.

Comment: please answer this question.

Comment: stackoverflow users please guide me. I have stuck to this problem since yesterday.I am new to c# asp.net.